# How to mimic the print function?

Tags: python

##### Context

I am making a command-line command line (ironic, I know) and I need to mimic the `print()` function.

##### Why?

I want to be able to change the print color (using colorama) without having to place `Fore.COLOR` everywhere.

##### What I have right now

```py
def pprint(*prompt):
  for strr in prompt:
    print(console_color+str(strr))
  return
```

Obviously, this wouldn't work with other arguments like `sep` or `end` which is why I need to mimic `print()`.

Comment: "Obviously, this wouldn't work with other arguments like sep or end which is why I need to mimic print()" I don't understand why this is a problem. Did you try specifying those *as parameters*, and then passing their values to the `print` call?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Unsure what you are talking about in both of your comments. "'Obviously, this wouldn't work with other arguments like sep or end which is why I need to mimic print()' I don't understand why this is a problem. Did you try specifying those as parameters, and then passing their values to the print call?" [Please give greater clarification on what you are asking.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `**kwarg` to take keyword arguments and pass them along to `print()`. Use a generator to concatenate with all the values.

```
def pprint(*strings, **kwarg):
    print(*(console_color+s for s in strings), **kwarg)
```